# The sum of an infinite series with integral

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration

$1+\dfrac{1}{9}+\dfrac{1}{45}+\dfrac{1}{189}+\dfrac{1}{729}+\dots=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(2n-1)\cdot 3^{n-1}}$

I got:
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(2n-1)\cdot 3^{n-1}}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\int\limits_0^1 x^{2n-2}\,dx}{3^{n-1}}=\dots$

And no idea how to impove.

Thx!

Comment: You could try and interchange integration and summation in $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1 \left(\frac{x^2}{3}\right)^{n-1}\,dx$$

Comment: How do you express that series to integral?
I've used riemann sum.

Answer (score 3):

After writing $\frac{1}{2n-1}$ as an integral, you have the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1 \left(\frac{x^2}{3}\right)^{n-1}\,dx.$$

Since the geometric series

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{x^2}{3}\right)^k$$

converges uniformly on the interval $[0,1]$, we can interchange summation and integration, and obtain

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)3^{(n-1)}} = \int_0^1 \frac{3}{3-x^2}\,dx.$$

The integral can be evaluated in different ways. With partial fraction decomposition

$$\frac{3}{3-x^2} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}-x} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+x}\right)$$

we get

$$\int_0^1 \frac{3}{3-x^2}\,dx = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left[\log (\sqrt{3}+x) - \log (\sqrt{3}-x)\right]_0^1 = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\log \frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{\sqrt{3}-1} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\log (2+\sqrt{3}).$$

Comment: (+1) the question was bumped and I wrote an answer that didn't look like yours on the surface, but upon closer inspection, turned out to be pretty close.

Comment: is it ok if you explain this example to me?